# Linear form, there exists a unique vector $z$ such that $f(w)=\langle w,z \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over the field $\mathbb{F}$ with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Then for every linear form $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ there exists a unique $z \in V$ such that $f(w)=\langle w,z \rangle$.

$V$ and its dual space $V^*$ are isomorphic because they have the same dimension and they are over the same field.

One such isomorphism is $\psi : V \to V^*$ where $\psi :  v \mapsto \langle v, \cdot \rangle $.

Then  $\psi(v)(w)=\langle v,w \rangle $ and the fact that $\psi$ is an isomorphism tells us that there indeed exists only one vector $v$ for which the form is expressed as $\langle v, \cdot \rangle$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Please consider using ``\langle \rangle`` to get $\langle \ \rangle$ instead of using the inequality signs to get $< \ >$. Which do you prefer $\langle u,v\rangle$ or $<u,v>$?

Comment: The argument seems fine to me, the one philosophical objection being that it is not constructive...

Comment: Your question is total unclear. You ask where to find a proof to a theorem, but then you don't specify the theorem. Then you go on to give a possible to proof to what could have been the theorem you were thinking of. What exactly is your **question**?

Comment: @FlybyNight I'm sorry. My first question was indeed where to find the theorem, then I started to think of a possible proof, and in the end I forgot what 
I wrote in the first line and I didn't reread my question. Thank you for correcting my post.

Comment: @IgorRivin Could you tell me what a constructive proof should look like?

Comment: @Bilbo Don't worry about the philosophical objection. There are many equally powerful and beautiful proofs which are not constructional. One nice example is the *Picard–Lindelöf theorem*. Philosophically speaking, not being able to construct something, or see something, or hear something, does not make its existence any less true.

$$ \ $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: @Bilbo for a constructive proof, you can pick an orthonormal basis and then express $\psi$ in terms of the dual basis. You will get some coefficients $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ of this expression and then, if $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ was the original basis, take a look to the vector $w=a_1v_1+\cdots a_nv_n$.

Comment: If $v^1, ..., v^n$ is the dual basis of $V^*$, then $V^* \ni f=a_1v^1 + ... + a_nv^n$. But I don't know how to express $\psi : V \rightarrow V^*$ using the dual basis

Comment: @Bilbo Note that every linear functional its determined by its values on a basis. Just note that $\psi=\sum_{I=1}^n\psi(v_i)v^i$